# Forcing the console.log error to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that runs when a link is clicked add the function creates a HTML element with an `id` of `my_ele`. So now I want to run another function every 2 sec. on two conditions.

### First condition

if element with the id of `my_ele` doesn't exists.

### Second condition

if the element with the id `my_ele` style is not equals to `block`

So I ran this code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(($("#my_ele").lenght == 0) || (document.getElementById('my_ele').style.display == 'none')){
        //run function here
    },2000);
```

Now I have no problem with the code because it works fine but my problem is that if the link hasn't been clicked which will create the element. I get an error in my console.log saying `cannot read property style of null` please how do I force this error to stop or is there a way to run my code to stop the error?

Comment: Typo: `$("#my_ele").lenght` should be `$("#my_ele").length`.

Comment: Why do you use both jQuery and plain JS ?

Comment: fist the *lenght* typo, and change the second part of the line to `!$("#my_ele").is(":visible")`.  Also, you don't need the parentheses around the two conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($('#my_ele').css('display') != 'block') { 
        // your code here...
    }
}, 2000);
```

You don't need to test the `#my_ele` exists, as if not exists the `display` is not 'block'.

Comment: This only works if the element is `display: block`, and as many elements can be `inline`, `inline-block`, `table`, `table-cell`, `table-row`, etc, this doesn't work in those instances.

Comment: Is the second condition in the question. The point of my answer is that you don't need to test if element exists, just the attribute value you whant to consider, as the jQuery `$` function return value is safe and so other jQuery api.

Comment: I see your point, but my point is the actual second conditional checks if it's `display == none`, not `display != block`.  You've changed the logic and introduced a massive hole in your logic.  Most elements are *not* display block by default, you'd have to set them to block with CSS or Javascript.

Comment: Please read the text of the question, where it sais *Second Condition*, not the code. I assumed the code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested)

You should check if element have some style only if the element exists.

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(($("#my_ele").length == 0) || ($("#my_ele").length > 0 && ($("#my_ele").style.display == 'none'))){
        //run function here
    },2000);
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `$("#my_ele").style.display`.  That's mixing Javascript and jQuery in a way that's unnecessary and wrong.  You would want to (if you want to use the plain Javascript `style` property) specify the DOM object like so:  `$("#my_ele")[0].style.display`.

Attempting to do it your way results in an error: "TypeError: $("#my_ele").style is undefined".

But seriously, why mix them?  jQuery provides a perfectly simply method, `is(":hidden")`.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your typo, removed the extraneous parentheses and changed the second conditional to jQuery:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($("#my_ele").length == 0 || $("#my_ele").is(":hidden")){
        //run function here
    },2000);
}
```

Further reading:  https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> ```
> They have a CSS display value of none.
> They are form elements with type="hidden".
> Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
> ```

====

Also a best practice to limit DOM scraping and improve efficiency is to set a variable to "cache" an element (note the `$myEle` variable):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var $myEle = $("#my_ele");
    if($myEle.length == 0 || $myEle.is(":hidden")){
        //run function here
    },2000);
}
```